# MATLAB slice function z-axis label reverse

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, matlab-figure, reverse

I'm using `slice` function for three dimensional plot as shown below

[image: Slice function]

z-axis is labeled as 'Thickness'.

What should I do if I want to see 0 z-axis at the top and 6 at the bottom?

Comment: did you try `flip(a,3)`? where `A` is your data and the 3rd dimension is the one on the z-axis?

Answer (score 1):

```
set(gca,'ZDir','reverse');
```

From the [official documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#zmw57dd0e50595):

> `'reverse'` — Reverse direction of increasing values:
>
> x-axis values decrease from left to right.
>
> y-axis values decrease from bottom to top (2-D view) or front to back (3-D view).
>
> z-axis values decrease pointing out of the screen (2-D view) or from bottom to top (3-D view).